# Getting Max Value in Rows for a Column

Tags: sql

I have a bit of SQL code that works well and I need to tweak it to get the max value for the RevisionNo column. Its not working for me and I not sure if I need a Having clause or how to best implement it.  Here is the working code:

```
SELECT ValueText FROM VariableValue
   WHERE (VariableID = 60) AND (DocumentID IN
               (SELECT DocumentID FROM Documents
                   WHERE (deleted = 0 and DocumentID IN
                             (SELECT DocumentID FROM Documents WHERE (Filename LIKE 'TCT-013963%.SLDASM'))))
```

This is not:

```
SELECT ValueText FROM VariableValue
   WHERE (VariableID = 60) AND MAX(RevisionNo) AND (DocumentID IN
               (SELECT DocumentID FROM Documents
                   WHERE (deleted = 0 and DocumentID IN
                             (SELECT DocumentID FROM Documents WHERE (Filename LIKE 'TCT-013963%.SLDASM')))))
```

The result I am getting with the query that runs returns two rows of from the valuetext column (this is a description field and I want the latest, hence the max value on the RevisionNo column).

|ValueText|RevisionNo|

|PRESSURE VESSEL FRONT END ASSY BNCT|1|

|PRESSURE VESSEL FRONT END ASSY NUBEAM|7|

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ValueText FROM VariableValue
   WHERE (VariableID = 60) AND (DocumentID IN
       (SELECT DocumentID FROM Documents
           WHERE (deleted = 0 and DocumentID IN
               (SELECT DocumentID FROM Documents WHERE (Filename LIKE 'TCT-013963%.SLDASM')))))
                   ORDER BY RevisionNo DESC
```

Comment: That was the ticket! Thank you.